# transpose data from row to column in desired times

Tags: vba, excel

I need to transpose a row of text in another column row times as shown below:
(Need to copy A1 to E1 text in related row 2 [here A2 to E3] times)

```
    A     B     C       D       E       F
1   Ab1     Ab2     Ab3     Ab4     Ab5     Total     
2   3   2   1   3   1   10
3                       
4   Ab1                 
5   Ab1                 
6   Ab1                 
7   Ab2                 
8   Ab2                 
9   Ab3                 
10  Ab4                 
11  Ab4                 
12  Ab4                 
13  Ab5
```

Answer (score 0):

This will loop through Row1

```
Sub Move_It()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim col As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim c As Range, x, y

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")    'actual name of worksheet

    With sh
        col = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, col))

        For Each c In rng.Cells    'loop through row 1
            x = c.Offset(1)

            For y = 1 To x

                .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1) = c

            Next y

        Next c

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: **Thanks** for the reply

Comment: Hi Dave, apart from above is it able to update those A2 to F2 values into an array with the help of above for loop only?

Comment: I don't understand the comment

Comment: Here I want to update A2 to F2 values into an array with the help of above 'For loop' pls suggest

Answer (score 0):

- Select the source range -> Right mouse click -> "Copy";
- Select top left cell of the target range -> Right mouse click -> "Paste Special" -> "Paste Special" dialogue -> Check "Transpose" Checkbox -> Click "OK"

You can record this as a macro.